# ASP.NET MVC 4 Multiselectlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am a new user of ASP.NET MVC4. I'm doing final project and I'm creating MVC4 web application.

In my web app when I am creating new Project, I should select multiple employees to it. I did research on multiselectlist, but no result.

Can you please provide me with step-by-step guide, how to fulfill my above stated objective.

How should I change my Project Model?

```
public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        this.Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    }

    public int Project_ID { get; set; }
    public string Project_Title { get; set; }
    public int Client_Id { get; set; }
    public string Project_Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Project_StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Project_EstEndDate { get; set; }
    public string Project_Status { get; set; }
    public int Project_Manager_Id { get; set; }
   **public string Project_Emps { get; set; }**

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Project_ActualEndDate { get; set; }
    public int Project_Tasks { get; set; }


    public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }   

}
```

Project_Emps is the column where Names of Selected Employees should be stored.

and how my controller and view should look like?

Comment: I have another model also for Employee, where Employees' initials are saved. I should get list of employee names from database and put them into dropdownlist on my Create Project View. And when I click Create Project button, all selected employees should be saved into Project_Emps column of Project table.

Comment: Yes int Emp_Id and to bind and string Emp_Name to display

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by creating a view model. It needs to contain an `IEnumerable<T>` property for the selected employee ID's

```
public class ProjectVM
{
  .... // add only those properties of Project that you need to edit

  [Display(Name = "Employees")]
  public int[] SelectedEmployees
  public SelectList EmployeeList { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model = new ProjectVM()
  model.EmployeeList = new SelectList(db.Employees, "Emp_Id", "Emp_Name");
  return View(model);
}
```

And the view

```
@model yourAssembly.ProjectVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedEmployees)
  @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedEmployees, Model.EmployeeList)
  ....
```

And post back to

```
public ActionResult Create(ProjectVM model)
{
  // model.SelectedEmployees contains a collection of the selected Employee Emp_Id values
```